# javascript true and true returning false in if statement?

Tags: javascript

In the plain javascript function. Both the values, min_chk and max_chk are true, but the if function still shows the alert. not able to figure why?

```
function Checkit(m,n){
return m>n;
}

var min_chk = Checkit(a,X);
var max_chk = Checkit(b,Y);
if ((min_chk === 'true') && (max_chk === 'true')){
...
    } else {
    alert('invalid range');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `===` operator returns `false` if the operands on both sides have different types. The boolean `true` and the string `"true"` have different types.

You should change your check just to

```
if (min_chk && max_chk)
```

Since `min_chk` and `max_chk` are already booleans, you don't need to compare them directly with `true`.

Answer (score 3):

The boolean `true` is not the same as the string `'true'`. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Or even better, get rid of `=== true` altogether. It's not necessary.

Comment: This is true. Since the return value of `CheckIt` is known, strict comparison is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the '' around true

```
function Checkit(m, n) {
    return m > n;
}

var min_chk = Checkit(a, X);
var max_chk = Checkit(b, Y);
if ((min_chk === true) && (max_chk === true)) {...
} else {
    alert('invalid range');
}
```